# Proper design for class that does resource-intensive setup

Tags: .net, oop

I have a class that performs a resource-intensive call to populate its data. Standard stuff. Here's a simplified version ...

```
public class Foo1 {
    private bool _IsLoaded;
    private string _Prop;
    private string _Prop2;

    public string Prop1 {
        get {
            ResourceIntensiveCall();
            return _Prop1;
        }
    }

    public string Prop2 {
        get {
            ResourceIntensiveCall();
            return _Prop2;
        }
    }

    private void ResourceIntensiveCall() {
        if ((!_IsLoaded)) {
            // Do processing...
            _IsLoaded = true;
        }
        _Prop1 = "something";
        _Prop2 = "stuff";
    }
}
```

This works fine, but violates the Microsoft.Design rule UsePropertiesWhereAppropriate because the property is doing too much work (albeit indirectly).

I could move the call to the constructor, but that violates the rule about doing too much work in a constructor.

I can use functions in place of properties, but this feels cumbersome if you have a lot of functions. Only the first client call does any real work anyway.

I could use a Public Init() method that client code must call before accessing any properties, but this is a design no-no because it make the class too brittle.

I thought about using a Foo1Factory to new-up Foo1 objects and marking the Foo1 constructor Internal to prevent the world from bypassing my factory.

What is considered a proper design for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> I could move the call to the constructor, but that violates the rule about doing too much work in a constructor.
>
> Only the first client call does any real work anyway.

Seeing as you only seem to need to do the call *once* per instance (my assumption - could be once for the whole process), I would do it in the constructor as the other options are worse.

Repeated code in properties or methods violates DRY and an `Init` method will like be something someone forgets.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is extracting my properties into a DataTransferObject:

```
public class Foo1Return {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Foo1 just has a method that does the calculations and returns the DTO:

```
public class Foo1 {
    public Foo1Return GetFoo1Results() {
        // Do processing...
        Foo1Return output = new Foo1Return();
        output.Prop1 = "something";
        output.Prop2 = "stuff";
        return output;
    }
}
```

Example client code:

```
Foo1 obj = new Foo1();
Foo1Results results = obj.GetFoo1Results();
```